# How to get result in different language using playlistItems?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={API_KEY}&part=snippet,status&videoDefinition=hd&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}
```

How can I get the value in English?
`hl=en` doesn't work.

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={API_KEY}&part=snippet,status&videoDefinition=hd&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&hl=en](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&part=snippet,status&videoDefinition=hd&playlistId=%7BPLAYLIST_ID%7D&hl=en)

Comment: Can you provide an example of `playlistId` you are experiencing a problem with?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison 
I used it like this, and registered the value in English for a few videos.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={API_KEY}&part=snippet,status&videoDefinition=hd&playlistId=PLvR6Uxe2wA_Hf4d4PuWAezY5ir0Vdnpa1&maxResults=6&pageToken=EAAaNalBUOkINA&lBUOkINA&lBUOkINA

The guide does not show a parameter that can be viewed by converting the language. Is it not supported?  
  
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Comment: @eunji I don't think it's possible the api get the results from playlistitems in different language.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thank you. I'll use a different API.